# Why $http_response_header is always null?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the reason for the heavy loaded server's timeout, and.. can not. For some reason `$http_response_header` is always null, I see it in prints. How could it be possible? it is always working on my other projects, but not here. May it be because the `hoster` has no `Apache` above? `PHP 7`.

```
$content=file_get_contents($url,false, stream_context_create(['http' => ["timeout"=>3]]));
$status_line = $http_response_header[0];
preg_match('{HTTP\/\S*\s(\d{3})}', $status_line, $match);
$status = json_encode($http_response_header);//$match[1];
```

Comment: You dont show anywhere where the `$http_response_header` is being assigned a value. Where does this variable come from?

Comment: @WesleySmith it's a reserved variable - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: @ADyson ahh, ...yuck

Comment: found this topic, maybe it can help you. Quite interesting issue ... - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72088

Comment: @AngelDeykov ah, Windows , quite right, hoster AFAIK has this installed. Thanks!